# ClassTemplateLoader not looking for template in specified path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, freemarker

My application is using Spring Boot 2.0.4 with Freemarker. 
In ClassTemplateLoader() constructor, I am passing class implementing FreemarkerTemplateEngine and path to templates for directory.

Dependency included:

```
org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.28:compile
```

Code snippet:

```
public FreemarkerTemplateEngine() {
        configuration =  new Configuration(Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS);
        configuration.setTemplateLoader(new ClassTemplateLoader(this.getClass(), "/template"));
    }
```

When I am trying to run application using mvn spring-boot:run, it gives me this error:

```
Cannot resolve template loader path [classpath:/templates/] to [java.io.File]: using SpringTemplateLoader as fallback
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

When I see the API of [ClassTemplateLoader](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/api/freemarker/cache/ClassTemplateLoader.html), I see the constructor should be fine.
Templates are at location 'template/', and when I refactor the directory to be 'templates/', it just works fine.

Question is 1.) Where in Spring or FreeMarker it is configured to search location of 'templates'? and 2.) What is the way that it can work with template/ location.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer - Cannot resolve template loader path [classpath:/templates/] to [java.io.File]: using SpringTemplateLoader as fallback
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
        at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:129)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.getTemplateLoaderForPath(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:345)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:297)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:120)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
```

Comment: `FreeMarkerConfigurer` has a `templatePath` property, which Spring uses to create and set the `TemplateLoader` in the `Configuration`. The stack trace shows that Spring's `FreeMarkerConfigurer` checks if the value of `templatePath` is correct, and that's where it fails. FreeMarker itself and hence any `TemplateLoader` is not yet involved at that point.

Comment: @ddekany: how can I correct it. I tried adding this, but no success:@Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() { 
        FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer(); 
        freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/path/to/template/");
        return freeMarkerConfigurer; 
    }

Comment: I have no experience using FreeMarker with Spring Boot... I would check if something else also creates a `FreeMarkerConfigurer` there (like Spring Boot auto-configuration maybe), and then it's used instead of yours. Just a guess though.